# Siblings without class trigger event

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a collapsable navigation bar .

```js
jQuery("li").click(function(e) {

  if (jQuery(this).hasClass('submenu')) {
    jQuery(e.currentTarget).children('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
ul.level_2,
ul.level_3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level_1">
  <li class="sibling first"><a href="home.html" title="Home" class="sibling first" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="active submenu"><strong class="active submenu" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="name">Brillen</strong>
    <ul class="level_2" style="display: none;">
      <li class="first"><a href="#" title="Herrenbrillen" class="first" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Herrenbrillen</span></a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Unterkategorie 1.1" class="last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Unterkategorie 1.1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu sibling"><a href="#" title="Sonnenbrillen" class="submenu sibling" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sonnenbrillen</span></a>
    <ul class="level_2" style="display: block;">
      <li class="submenu first"><a href="#" title="Varianten &amp; mehr" class="submenu first" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Varianten &amp; mehr</span></a>
        <ul class="level_3">
          <li class="first"><a href="#" title="Produkte mit Varianten" class="first" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Produkte mit Varianten</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Produkte mit Konfigurator" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Produkte mit Konfigurator</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Produkte mit Staffelpreis" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Produkte mit Staffelpreis</span></a></li>
          <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Alle Sonnenbrillen" class="last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Alle Sonnenbrillen</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Angebote" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Angebote</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Neuheiten" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Neuheiten</span></a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Unterkategorie 2.1" class="last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Unterkategorie 2.1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu sibling"><a href="#" title="Kontaktlinsen" class="submenu sibling" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Kontaktlinsen</span></a>
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li class="first last"><a href="#" title="Unterkategorie 3.1" class="first last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Unterkategorie 3.1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sibling"><a href="blog.html" title="Blog" class="sibling" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Blog</span></a></li>
  <li class="sibling"><a href="%C3%BCber-uns.html" title="Über Uns" class="sibling" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Über Uns</span></a></li>
  <li class="sibling last"><a href="kontakt.html" title="Kontakt" class="sibling last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Kontakt</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

There are more collapsables. Those elements have the class "submenu".
If i click an item in the menu levels 2/3 is collapses the menu, even if it doesnt have the class "submenu".
I want the items with the "submenu" class to act as a toggle and the rest to act like links.

Answer (score 0):

your parent click is triggering when child is clicked, you can prevent it by using the `e.stopPropagation();` but you have to prevent it.

like this

```
 $("li:not(.submenu)").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
```

```js
jQuery("li").click(function(e) {
  jQuery(e.currentTarget).children('ul').toggle();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});
$("li:not(.submenu)").click(function(e) {
  window.location = e.target.parentElement.href;
  return false
});
```

```css
ul.level_2,
ul.level_3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level_1">
  <li class="sibling first"><a href="home.html" title="Home" class="sibling first" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="active submenu"><strong class="active submenu" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="name">Brillen</strong>
    <ul class="level_2" style="display: none;">
      <li class="first"><a href="#" title="Herrenbrillen" class="first" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Herrenbrillen</span></a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Unterkategorie 1.1" class="last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Unterkategorie 1.1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu sibling"><a href="#" title="Sonnenbrillen" class="submenu sibling" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sonnenbrillen</span></a>
    <ul class="level_2" style="display: block;">
      <li class="submenu first"><a href="#" title="Varianten &amp; mehr" class="submenu first" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Varianten &amp; mehr</span></a>
        <ul class="level_3">
          <li class="first"><a href="#" title="Produkte mit Varianten" class="first" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Produkte mit Varianten</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Produkte mit Konfigurator" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Produkte mit Konfigurator</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Produkte mit Staffelpreis" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Produkte mit Staffelpreis</span></a></li>
          <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Alle Sonnenbrillen" class="last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Alle Sonnenbrillen</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Angebote" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Angebote</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Neuheiten" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Neuheiten</span></a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Unterkategorie 2.1" class="last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Unterkategorie 2.1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu sibling"><a href="#" title="Kontaktlinsen" class="submenu sibling" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Kontaktlinsen</span></a>
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li class="first last"><a href="https://google.com" title="Unterkategorie 3.1" class="first last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Unterkategorie 3.1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sibling"><a href="blog.html" title="Blog" class="sibling" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Blog</span></a></li>
  <li class="sibling"><a href="%C3%BCber-uns.html" title="Über Uns" class="sibling" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Über Uns</span></a></li>
  <li class="sibling last"><a href="kontakt.html" title="Kontakt" class="sibling last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Kontakt</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

or **Better approach**
Just check

```
if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
```

```js
jQuery("li").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    jQuery(e.currentTarget).children('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
ul.level_2,
ul.level_3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="level_1">
  <li class="sibling first"><a href="home.html" title="Home" class="sibling first" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="active submenu"><strong class="active submenu" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="name">Brillen</strong>
    <ul class="level_2" style="display: none;">
      <li class="first"><a href="#" title="Herrenbrillen" class="first" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Herrenbrillen</span></a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Unterkategorie 1.1" class="last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Unterkategorie 1.1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu sibling"><a href="#" title="Sonnenbrillen" class="submenu sibling" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Sonnenbrillen</span></a>
    <ul class="level_2" style="display: block;">
      <li class="submenu first"><a href="#" title="Varianten &amp; mehr" class="submenu first" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Varianten &amp; mehr</span></a>
        <ul class="level_3">
          <li class="first"><a href="#" title="Produkte mit Varianten" class="first" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Produkte mit Varianten</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Produkte mit Konfigurator" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Produkte mit Konfigurator</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Produkte mit Staffelpreis" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Produkte mit Staffelpreis</span></a></li>
          <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Alle Sonnenbrillen" class="last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Alle Sonnenbrillen</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Angebote" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Angebote</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Neuheiten" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Neuheiten</span></a></li>
      <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Unterkategorie 2.1" class="last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Unterkategorie 2.1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu sibling"><a href="#" title="Kontaktlinsen" class="submenu sibling" aria-haspopup="true" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Kontaktlinsen</span></a>
    <ul class="level_2">
      <li class="first last"><a href="#" title="Unterkategorie 3.1" class="first last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Unterkategorie 3.1</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sibling"><a href="blog.html" title="Blog" class="sibling" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Blog</span></a></li>
  <li class="sibling"><a href="%C3%BCber-uns.html" title="Über Uns" class="sibling" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Über Uns</span></a></li>
  <li class="sibling last"><a href="kontakt.html" title="Kontakt" class="sibling last" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Kontakt</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i thought my e.stopPropagation(); would stop this.

Comment: @Bladerxdxi No it has to go for the click of the parent element.

Comment: the code examples also block the events from the actual links

Comment: @bladeexdi you can remove  propagation code and try it it should pass easily

Comment: @Bladerxdxi pleaes check my first snippet.