# jquery click event on nested elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am newbie for jquery. I have nested `li` with same name. And I want to set left position of `div` with class open according to clicked `li` level. But when I click inside `li` it take position of first.

Here is my code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open">
  <ul>
    <li class="child">
      <a href="#">link1</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="child">
          <a href="#">menu link1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>
  $(".child").on("click", function() {
    var l = $(this).parents('ul').length
    var a = 101 * l;
    $(".open").css({
      "left": "-" + a + "%"
    })
  })
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting to apply this to all child in the tree or just the subchild?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720313/siblings-without-class-trigger-event/53720413#53720413 check this out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the click is happening in both when you click the inner li, you can use stopPropagation inside the event to prevent that

Answer (score 1):

You can stopt the propagation with `event.stopPropagation();`.
I added a `console.log()` so that you see what is clicked.

```js
$(".child").on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var l = $(this).parents('ul').length
  var a = 101 * l;
  console.log("click: " + $(this).find(">a").text());
  $(".open").css({
    "left": "-" + a + "%"
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open">
  <ul>
    <li class="child">
      <a href="#">link1</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="child">
          <a href="#">menu link1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to disable the bubbling

```
$(".child").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // diasble default action
    event.stopPropagination();  // disable bubbling to parent event
    var l = $(this).parents('ul').length
    var a = 101*l;
    $(".open").css({
      "left": "-" + a + "%"
    })
  })
```

**not tested**